# regex find method calls with specific number of arguments

Tags: javascript, regex, eclipse

I'm trying to find all occurencas of certain method, but only with specified number of arguments(5):

so let's say I have different methods with the same name and different set of args.

```
.method(asd,asd,asd,asd,asd,asd,asd)
.method(asd,asd,asd,asd,asd)
.method(asd,asd,asd)
```

I've tried something like that: `\.open\((?:.*?\,){4}[^,]*?\)` but it gives back all methods with 5 and more args:

```
.method(asd,asd,asd,asd,asd,asd,asd)
.method(asd,asd,asd,asd,asd)
```

I need only those with 4. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [When asking regex questions, always add the tag for the specific programming language or tool (e.g., Perl, Python, or Java; vi, emacs, or ɢɴᴜ grep; etc.) you are using.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Answer (score 2):

works for me:

```
egrep "\(([^,]*,){4}[^,]*\)"  method
```

Suggestion from comment:

```
egrep "open\s?\(([^,)]*,){4}[^,)]*\)"  methodfile
```

Comment: It's worth noting that it wont work properly, if there are nested function calls with multiple arguments inside the arguments (or if the arguments contain commas inside quotes). Additionally, that would also match against ".open(foo, bar, zor) .open(foo, bar, baz)", so adding ")" to the negative character classes might be a good idea.

Comment: Yes, and I have to admit, that I put aboves strings into a file called 'method', so the method name would need to go into the expression, maybe separated by an blank.

Comment: it kinda worked for me but I had modify it a bit:      \.open\(([^,)]*,){4}[^,]*\)   . otherwise it would match something like that, too:  .method(asd, asd);,,,)

Comment: Don't I see the difference, or was that comment started before I included Rinuwise's suggestion?

Comment: exactly, as I've been writing your comment wasn't there yet. weired

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
\.method\(\w+(,\w+){3}\)
```

only returns the ones with exactly 4 params. You may want to account for optional space-chars:

```
\.method\s*\(\s*\w+(\s*,\s*\w+\s*){3}\)
```

### EDIT

Since you've tagged your question with Eclipse, I assume you're familiar with Java. The following:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = ".method(asd,asd,asd,asd,asd,asd,asd) \n" +
        ".method(asd,asd,asd,asd)                       \n" +
        ".method(asd,asd,asd)                           \n" +
        "Foo.method(a,b,c,d)                            \n";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\.method\\(\\w+(,\\w+){3}\\)").matcher(text);

    while(m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group());
    }
  }
}
```

produces the output:

```
.method(asd,asd,asd,asd)
.method(a,b,c,d)
```

as you can see on Ideone: http://ideone.com/RvTxw

HTH

Comment: I had trouble get it working, tried in eclipse and cygwin (have no linux currently)