# Regex to find method calls

Tags: java, regex

I want to find any method call in given code. I am splitting code with semicolon as delimiter. In the end I am interested in finding names of methods which have been called in given code.

I need a regular expression to match the method call pattern.

Comment: If you want a correct solution then the answer is: it's practically impossible.

Comment: Not only practical, but even theoretical. Java (the language) is not a regular language so it can't be parsed by regular expressions.

Comment: Agreed; this is incredibly messy. You'd have to match: bare function calls and function calls on instances but not function definitions. Also, what would you do with function calls nested in function calls, e.g. `map.get(map.get(123))`? Ugh.

Comment: @his This is nitpicking but since there is an upper limit on the size of the source code, the language is finite and thus theoretically regular.

Comment: Do you have to start with source files, or can you work with class files?  There are bytecode libraries that could give you the tools to do the job on class files.

Comment: @biziclop The Java grammar is not a regular grammar. If you set an upper limit for size than you can write down every possible Java source and put that in alternative groups - quite impractical. But that is a *different* way to describe those possible source files. The Java grammar -that is the definitive description of the language- is not regular.

Comment: @his I understand what you say but grammar != language. Either way, to write something constructive: OP shouldn't even attempt to parse the language using a CF grammar, tools like ANTLR are the way to go.

Comment: Thanx all for replying :)
Lets make it simple and suppose that there are no nested function calls within function call.I saw a similar question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326752/regex-find-method-calls-with-specific-number-of-arguments) but this was about specific number of arguments. I want expression where no nested calls and with no limit on arguments. hope you understood :)

Comment: For example: 
I have array of strings: tokens("int a","abc(a)","a=2")
So i want match of "abc(a)" (where number of arguments can vary).

Comment: @beerbajay
please have a look.

Comment: This is still a pain. e.g. `a = b+c(d)`

Comment: Note also that semicolons are also valid in comments and in string literals.

Comment: Assuming no nested function calls isn't enough. You also need to worry about nested blocks. Regexes come nowhere near this task. Why are you insisting that the parser be regular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once had to figure out if a string contains a Java method call (including method names containing non-ASCII characters).

The following worked quite well for me, though it also finds constructor calls. Hope it helps.

```
/**
 * Matches strings like {@code obj.myMethod(params)} and
 * {@code if (something)} Remembers what's in front of the parentheses and
 * what's inside.
 * <p>
 * {@code (?U)} lets {@code \\w} also match non-ASCII letters.
 */
public static final Pattern PARENTHESES_REGEX = Pattern
        .compile("(?U)([.\\w]+)\\s*\\((.*)\\)");

/*
 * After these Java keywords may come an opening parenthesis.
 */
private static List<String> keyWordsBeforeParens = Arrays.asList("while", "for",
            "if", "try", "catch", "switch");

private static boolean containsMethodCall(final String s) {
    final Matcher matcher = PARENTHESES_REGEX.matcher(s);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        final String beforeParens = matcher.group(1);
        final String insideParens = matcher.group(2);
        if (keyWordsBeforeParens.contains(beforeParens)) {
            System.out.println("Keyword: " + beforeParens);
            return containsMethodCall(insideParens);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Method name: " + beforeParens);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I need similar regex to find a specific method call, For example it finds the "setValue" method call. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @MeysamKarimi: A regex like `setValue\s*\(` would probably get you all method calls and the method definition. If you're working with regexes, I'd recommend testing them with something like https://regex101.com/ Are you using grep for your task?

Answer (score 4):

For qualified calls {i.e., calls in this form: [objectName|className].methodName(..) }, I've been using:

```
(\.[\s\n\r]*[\w]+)[\s\n\r]*(?=\(.*\))
```

When unqualified calls are present {i.e., calls in this form: methodName(..) }, I've been using:

```
(?!\bif\b|\bfor\b|\bwhile\b|\bswitch\b|\btry\b|\bcatch\b)(\b[\w]+\b)[\s\n\r]*(?=\(.*\))
```

Although, this will also find constructors.

Answer (score 0):

```
File f=new File("Sample.java"); //Open a file
String s;
FileReader reader=new FileReader(f); 
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(reader); //Read file
while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
    String regex="\\s(\\w+)*\\(((\\w+)*?(,)?(\\w+)*?)*?\\)[^\\{]";
    Pattern funcPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = funcPattern.matcher(s); //Matcher is used to match pattern with string 
    if(m.find()){
        System.out.printf(group(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is generally a good idea to add some kind of description of how this code solves the given problem. Please [edit] your answer to add such a description.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one would work but it doesn't match secondary regexes for the arguments:

```java
String regex = "\\s*(\\w+?)\\s*\\(((\\w+?)\\s*,?\\s*)*\\)\\s*";
```